# Why does ADX caching result from related dimension table/mv/function

Tags: kql, azure-data-explorer, adx

I'm testing materialized views based on the queries below:

1. Lookup to another materialized view (bar_mv) storing last timestamps in field LAST_FOO_TS for some key(a,b,c)

```
.create materialized-view  with (dimensionMaterializedViews = "bar_mv") 
foo_mv on table events_table{
events_table 
|lookup materialized_view('bar_mv') on a,b,c
|where TIMESTAMP > LAST_FOO_TS
}
```

2. Lookup to stored function (bar_v) returning last timestamps in field LAST_FOO_TS for some key(a,b,c)

```
.create materialized-view
foo_mv1 on table events_table{
events_table 
|lookup bar_v() on a,b,c
|where TIMESTAMP > LAST_FOO_TS
}
```

In both cases, looks like ADX is caching results of the lookup materialized view/function and not refresing it for long time or ever.
Is there any way to force refresh of those?

I tried both ways described in the details.

Answer (score 0):

Records in the materialized view that have already been materialized are not refreshed following changes to the dimension table. See more details in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/materialized-views/materialized-view-create#query-parameter):

`Records in the view's source table (the fact table) are materialized only once. Updates to the dimension tables don't have any impact on records that have already been processed from the fact table.`